# Android AOSP : Talkback when device is locked

Tags: android, accessibility, android-source, talkback

In AOSP code i am trying to enable the Talk-back i.e. to speak "Device locked" when lock screen is shown either due to sleep time or manual lock

However, i managed to speak out "device Locked" on manual lock by overriding the dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(..) method by setting the contentdescrition to "Device locked" in the KeyGuardview class but i am not able to do it in automatic elapsed sleep time flow (lock screen is enabled in the background when i touch again the device)

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {       
    if(event != null){          
        event.setContentDescription(getResources().getString(R.string.device_locked));
    }
    return super.dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(event);
}
```

Does anyone have any idea ?

Comment: one question to all - Is talk-back app speaks out even after screen is off ? Some one has already raised it but no acceptable answer found - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558522/android-accessibilityservice-whan-screen-off Anyone ?